What's the most goals scored by a team from outside the penalty area in a single match?
Earlier today, Turkey beat Georgia 3-1 in a Euro 2024 group match, with all three of Turkey's goals being scored from outside the penalty area. There can't be too many occasions where that's happened, and it's got me thinking: what's the most goals a team has scored from outside the box in a single match? It doesn't have to have been all their goals (if they scored seven and six were from outside the area, that still counts).
I'll narrow this down to any top-flight professional league or any recognised FIFA international.

Definitely too broad at the moment, when you get something like a 12-0 thrashing in a Sunday league match, it's quite likely more than 3 of them were scored from outside the area.

The 2002 Madagascar Champion's League final which ended 149–0 might be a contender. If not, maybe the 2002 Australia–American Samoa World Cup qualifier which ended 31–0.
